# How to get rid of access denied to .pkgdef file

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2017

I'm having the problem that I can't start visual studio due to an access problem for a .pkgdef file:
C:\apps\visualstudio\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DSLTextTemplatingRegistry_x86.pkgdef I always get 80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED (according to visual studios ActivityLog.xml)

The problem started after visual studio crashed once.

**Steps taken already:**

- Restarted PC multiple times
- Trying to look up the problem via google and microsoft solutions
- Deleted the roaming data
- Tried to start without any third party features (thus using:
  devenv.exe /SafeMode   as detailed here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature)

**System data:**

Visual Studio 2017 communiuty edition installed on c:\apps (instead of c:\prorgam files) and windows 7.

My question here is: What else can I do to get rid of that problem (without reinstalling if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have this problem anymore, but i will an answer for others that encounter the same issue.

If you delete the data in your 'local' appdata folder ( specifically the private.bin files).

VS2017 will start up again.  For some reason these files can become corrupt during installs of extensions or updates to VS itself.